# How could I get the file running on JBoss AS?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I'm recoding my project.
It's older version running well on JBoss EAP 6.0

Now, I found an logical error in the code( older version)

The new version would run correctly only under new logic.

But the older version just works well.

I hope to get the war file on JBoss Server, to check the code

Does anyone could show me how to get the file ?

Comment: You know people will probably be able to help you more if you show some code or something.

Comment: I do not past the code because the logic itself is not important. I really care is how to get the old file on server.

Comment: You know as per definition, a war file is a JAR file used to distribute a collection of JavaServer Pages, Java Servlets, Java classes, XML files, tag libraries, static web pages (HTML and related files) and other resources that together constitute a web application. So it is not clear which file actually do you want to retrieve and mind you in such a war file the java files are class files and not source file. Unless you have the source files kept somewhere you will have a hard time to do anything with the class files.

Comment: Thanks, Omoro. I am about to get the war file, and disassembler the class file to see the source code..